# Ubuntu 20.04: Scroll doesn't work for wireless mouse after system wakes up from suspended state

Tags: usb, 20.04, suspend, mouse, bluetooth

I have a Dell Vostro laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. I also have a Microsoft Wireless Mobile mouse connected through a USB bluetooth receiver. The mouse works without any issue till I suspend the laptop for a while. When the laptop resumes from suspension, the mouse scroll functionality doesn't work at all. I have to use the laptop's touchpad to scroll around.

I can get the scroll functionality working again if I pull out and reinsert the USB bluetooth receiver. I hate to do this each time I get my laptop wake up from suspension.

Is there a system configuration change I can make to automatically fix the scroll issue each time my laptop wakes up from suspension?

Comment: Please Note: This issue never happened when my laptop was running Ubuntu 18.04 previously.

Comment: A kernel problem. Problem is that the driver does not seem reentrant after suspend. Some power feature might prevent it. So look for your driver (e.g. with `lsusb`) and search for a possible bug report. If you expect us to help, we would need such information and the output of 'journalctl -f` which you should execute **BEFORE** you go into suspend.

Comment: I recreated a similar setup (Dell Vostro, Ubuntu 20.04) but with a Wireless Microsoft Keyboard / Mouse - not bluetooth. This happens in this case too. This is solved by unplugging and re-plugging the little usb dongle (the wireless receiver). Can you try turning off and on the bluetooth module?

Comment: This problem is driving me crazy! Did you ever find a solution? I don't want to need to unplug and replug the USB dongle every time I wake the computer up. Thanks!