# How to require password upon wake from hibernation instead of before?

Tags: shortcut-keys, hibernate, authentication, wakeup

I have a new Lenovo ThinkPad E15 that came with Windows 10 installed. I added Ubuntu 20.04 as an option (dual-boot).

After some tricky configuration, I eventually got hibernation working.

And using "Keyboard Shortcuts", I set up this hotkey to trigger `systemctl hibernate`:

[image]

Unfortunately I have 2 problems:

1. Upon typing that hotkey combo, I'm prompted for a password. Upon providing the correct password, the computer hibernates. I'd prefer it to instantly hibernate without prompting for any password.

[image]

2. Upon wake, I'm *not* prompted for a password. This seems like a security problem. I *do* want my laptop to require a password upon waking.

How can I fix those issues? Thanks!

Comment: See also my potentially related question "Ubuntu 20.04: Scroll wheel doesn't work for wireless mouse after system wakes up" https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214

Comment: "*After some tricky configuration, I eventually got hibernation working.*" - something you did caused the problem you are currently experiencing.  In order to solve that problem, it would be best if you would include the context and details surrounding your original problem as well as all of the actions you took to solve that problem. My guess is that the original problem was not solved in the best way so it is causing new ones.

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for your response. I've had so many problems with Ubuntu 20.04 on my ThinkPad E15 (e.g. it crashed twice yesterday, it has the hibernation problems, the mouse scroll wheel problem, etc etc) that I think I'll install Debian instead today once I can figure out the appropriate architecture file at https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst. I've heard that Debian tends to be rock-solid for ThinkPads (although I see no mention of E15 in particular anywhere, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

This [forum comment](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/re-visiting-hibernate-on-ubuntu/15953/25) led me to **[this blog post](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-ubuntu.html)**, whose steps I followed.

My system no longer prompts me for my password when I press the keyboard shortcut that runs `systemctl hibernate`.

I know that "link-only" answers are frowned upon, but the article is too long and detailed to replicate here, so I figured it would be "better than nothing" to report back and at least share the link that helped me out.

I also made sure that the article is available on [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-ubuntu.html).